# What properties does $f$ have to fulfil such that $\log f(x)$ is concave?

Tags: proof-writing, logarithms

Given a function $f$ with $f: \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$. I want to show that $f^*$ with $f^*(x) = \log f(x)$ is concave. Judging from the plot this is true, however, $f$ is a quite complex function.

What I know is that for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} f^*(n)$ is zero. Does this suffice, or do I also have to show that $f$ is a (strictly) increasing function? Or is there anything else I forgot?

Comment: You need stricter conditions than just the limit, as $f$ can oscillate, .e.g. $f(x)=\sin(x)$. So some kind of monotonicity would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative has to be negative, this means:
$$y'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$ so 
$$y''=\frac{f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2}{f(x)^2}<0$$

Comment: I hoped to avoid calculating the second derivative, because it is probably a hard task. But I can try.

Comment: And thank you for downvoting me!

Comment: I did not downvote.